# Is $\mathbb R$ terminal among Archimedean fields?

Tags: field-theory, order-theory

I was wondering why metrics and norms are always defined to be real, rather than generalized to some other fields (or whatever). The best guess I have so far is:

> Because every Archimedean ordered field is (up to unique isomorphism) a subfield of $\mathbb R$ anyway.

But is that actually true? And if it is, can it be strengthened to "every Achimedean ordered ring"? Or even semiring?

I know $\mathbb R$ is the only *complete* Archimedean field. But a priori, I suppose there could be non-complete examples that cannot be completed (without losing the Archimedean property).

Comment: Duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21435/equivalency-of-archimedian-fields-properties

Comment: My guess is that we understand $\mathbb R$ pretty well, and it is nicely behaved. I had a discussion about this two years ago with two classmates. Eventually the teacher (measure theory) told us that you can define a valuation into any ordered Abelian group. My second guess would be that completeness is just very nice to have, just like complete Boolean-algebras are used for Boolean-valued models because incomplete ones could have critical holes that possibly remove well-definability.

Comment: I guess this depends on your definition of Archimedean, but I think $\mathbb{C}$ is considered Archimedean although it is not ordered. So $\mathbb{R}$ is the only complete Archimedean **ordered** field.

Comment: @Joel, it's not clear to me what "Archimedean" would mean in the absence of an ordering. Please elaborate.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : If $K$ is a field with an absolute value $|| : K \to \mathbb{R}^+$ (satisfying $|x| = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$, $|ab| = |a| . |b|$, and $|a+b| \le |a| + |b|$), we say it is archimedean if integers (or precisely the image of the map $1_{\mathbb{Z}} \mapsto 1_K$) are not bounded. This definition implies an archimedean field with an absolute value is of characteristic $0$, so contains $\mathbb{Q}$. And it turns out all of then are contained in $\mathbb{C}$. Non archimedean complete fields with an absolute value include $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I defer to Proposition 12 (well... the *second* Proposition 12...) and Theorems 14 and 15 in [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11923/completion-of-rational-numbers-via-cauchy-sequences/12009#12009).

It is not hard to construct an argument that $\mathbb{R}$ is a final object in the category of Archimedean fields from these results. For example see the notes that Pete L. Clark links to on the same page.

Comment: Your Theorem 14 takes nicely care of my principal question. I'm still wondering about possible strengthenings. I'm looking for a sort of minimal set of things one might want to do with the metric such that only substructures of the reals satisfy them.

Comment: @kahen: We need a unique morphism from each Archimedean ordered field into $\mathbb{R}$ in order for it to be terminal. Unless I'm mistaken, there are _two_ embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ (with its usual absolute value) into $\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be terminal.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: one of these embeddings does not preserve order. (We're implicitly considering the category of Archimedean ordered fields with _order-preserving_ field homomorphisms).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68189/field-bigger-than-mathbbr/68313#68313) to a related question.  I think one can show as a consequence of this stuff that the Dedekind completion of a non-Archimedean ordered field is actually not a field.