# Can a metric space have a distance function that maps to any arbitrary ordered field other than the set of positive Real Numbers?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, field-theory

All the definitions I've found on line for a metric space is that a Metric Space is an ordered pair (M, p) where M is a non-empty set and p is a distance function where,

$p: M \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

I was curious if this could be further generalised to the subset of all positive value in any arbitrary ordered field F, i.e.

$p : M \times M \rightarrow F^{+}$

Where $F^{+} =  \{f \in F \: |\: f \geq_{F} 0_{F}\}$

With  $0_{F}$ being the additive inverse for $F$ and

$\geq_{F}$ is the greater than or equal operator for $F$.

Any tips/suggestions/comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, David

Comment: Not exactly the same question but you would probably be interested by Nate Ackerman's answer in this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104646/topological-spaces-determined-by-generalized-metric-spaces

Comment: Fucken legend!! thanks to that I was able to find the answer to my question. It is a generalised metric space (I was google searching the wrong terms!)

Thanks so much!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_metric

Comment: This was also asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762433/should-a-metric-always-map-into-mathbfr?rq=1) where the answer takes the metric into ordered abelian groups